# Trabalhando com imagem Base64 no Android Studio

Tags: android, base64, imageview

Eu tenho um app no Android Studio e gostaria de usar imagem Base64 nas ImageView e ImageButton.

Eu já sei converter a imagem (da pasta Drawable) para String, mas não sei como aplicar isto como background dos meus itens.

Existe como? Ou existe como eu pegar uma String de uma imagem base64 convertida na Internet mesmo e aplicar como imagem dentro do Android Studio?

Comment: Não está muito claro para mim o que você quer fazer. Me parecem dois problemas diferentes. Pelo que entendi, você tem uma imagem na pasta Drawable e quer colocá-la como fundo dos seus elementos. Onde base64 entra nisso? Além disso, você está falando em pegar uma imagem base64 na Internet e aplicar nos seus itens. É um problema mais concreto, mas isso é algo dinâmico-- não é algo que você vai fazer em uma opção do Android Studio e sim via código, certo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andiie, primeiro você terá que converter sua String **Base64** para um `Bitmap`, e a partir deste criar um `BitmapDrawable`.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), decodedByte);
```

Depois de convertida, você pode utilizar o `Drawable` como **background**.

---

**Veja mais aqui:**

[How to convert a Base64 string into a BitMap image to show it in a ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview)

[How to convert a Bitmap to Drawable in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415619/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-to-drawable-in-android)